# How can I turn the bul on and off: but with only using 1 button?

Tags: javascript

It´s a code from w3schools.
I want to turn the bul on and off but with the same button.
As simple as possible.
Thx for every answer :)

```
<html>
<body>

<h2>What Can JavaScript Do?</h2>

<p>JavaScript can change HTML attribute values.</p>


<button onclick="document.getElementById('myImage').src='pic_bulbon.gif'">Turn on the light</button>

<img id="myImage" src="pic_bulboff.gif" style="width:100px">

<button onclick="document.getElementById('myImage').src='pic_bulboff.gif'">Turn off the light</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: On option is on button click, check the `src` of the image. If it is `pic_bulboff.gif` change it to `pic_bulbon.gif` and vice versa.

Comment: I tried this. But how can I check if the src is pic_buloff.gif odr pic_bulon.gif?

Comment: what's a bul ? is that a dev term ? :)) So you have some code copy pasted from a tutorial. And now you came here asking people to improve it so you achieve what you want. Where's your contribution ? Except copy pasting code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it.

```js
// Add an on-click handler to the button
document.getElementById("action-btn").onclick = (e) => {
    // Get the image
    let image = document.getElementById("myImage");
    // Check for the word "off"
    if (image.src.includes("off")) {
        // Set image to alternate
        image.src = "pic_bulbon.gif";
        // Set text of button
        e.srcElement.textContent = "Turn off the light";
    }
    else {
        image.src = "pic_bulboff.gif";
        e.srcElement.textContent = "Turn on the light";
    }
}
```

```html
<h2>What Can JavaScript Do?</h2>
<p>JavaScript can change HTML attribute values.</p>
<button id="action-btn">Turn on the light</button>
<img id="myImage" src="pic_bulboff.gif" style="width:100px">
```